# Why does the compiler remove unused structs but not classes

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, compiler-optimization

I have the fallowing code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var str = new DummyStruct();
    var testClass = new DummyClass();
}
```

Neither the class or the struct have any implementation. But when I look at the code after a release build using ILSpy I get

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new DummyClass();
}
```

So my question is: Why does the compiler ignore the instantiation of a struct but not the one of a class ?

Comment: The C# compiler is pretty conservative about removing dead code.  It is the job of the jitter, it knows a lot more about what code actually does.  But it is dead easy for the "default constructor" of a struct, neither C# nor the CLR permit defining one.  Having to write "new" is in itself fairly useless, but inspired by the definite assignment rule in C#.  Not necessary in VB.NET or C++/CLI for example.

Comment: @HansPassant That's a very informative comment. but after a bit of research I discovered that it's just C# that doesn't allow the creation a of a parameterless constructor, it seams to be totally OK from the CLR's point of view. Do you by any chance have any documentation that shows the opposite ?

Comment: Ecma-335 chapter II.13.2, rationale brackets.

Comment: @HansPassant I've read exactly the same passage but it describes the way that the CLR does it, it doesn't specify anywhere that you cannot create a default constructor, for example the C# specs are really specific about that at 11.13.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var str = new DummyStruct();`, when `str` is subsequently unused, doesn't do anything. In particular, no constructor of `DummyStruct` gets called.

`var testClass = new DummyClass();`, when `testClass` is subsequently unused, does potentially do something. The constructor of `DummyClass` may have side effects. Even if it doesn't currently have side effects as far as the compiler can see, if it resides in a different assembly, it may have side effects at run time if a different version of the library is used.

Comment: So is there no way for the creation of a struct to have side effects ? I initially thought about static constructors, but those work differently for structs from what I've seen.

Comment: @toby A `struct` constructor that takes parameters may have side effects, but C# doesn't even let you create a parameterless `struct` constructor, the compiler treats any `new Struct()` as just `default(Struct)`.